# Batch file - get file name without extension from passed parameter

Tags: batch-file

i am trying to create a batch file to run:

```
.tex --> .dvi : latex filename.tex  
.dvi --> .ps  : dvips -o filename.ps filename 
.ps --> .pdf  : ps2pdf filename.ps
```

I tried:

```
latex %1
dvips -o %~n%1.ps %n%1
ps2pdf %~n%1.ps
```

assuming that `~n` will give me the file name without the extension of a passed file. However, it doesn't work (apart from the first line). Does anyone know the correct version?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, some trial and error gave me

```
latex %1 
dvips -o %~n1.ps %~n1
ps2pdf %~n1.ps
```

which does the trick

Comment: You probably should surround the arguments in quotes in case the filenames contain spaces. (e.g. `dvips "%~n1.ps" "%~n1"``).

Comment: I thought these may be useful to know:
Fully qualified name: %~f1
Drive: %~d1
Path: %~p1
File name: %~n1
File extension: %~x1
Short filename: %~sn1
Short file extension: %~sx1
Drive and directory: %~dp1
File name and extension: %~nx1

Comment: ... and for the fully qualified path, minus the extension, you can use `"%~dpn1"`

Answer (score 1):

1. You don't need to specify the extension when executing `latex` and `dvips`.
2. But `ps2pdf` needs the extension.
3. The following works because I use this everyday. Trust me!

```
rem this is a batch file, named mybatch.bat
rem it takes a filename without extension

echo off

latex %1
dvips %1
ps2pdf %1.ps
```

Comment: Traditionally, echo off is preceded by `@`, as this will prevent it from being echoed to the console and is the first thing in a production batch file, also, it's standard for comments to use `:: ` instead of `rem `, finally: rem should not be used to echo output to the console, for that, use `echo` instead (for a blank line, use `echo.`).